# Matlab - find function between matrix and cell array

Tags: matlab, matrix, bsxfun

I’ve  a  matrix  A = (4*4) and a cell array B {4,1}. I’d like to find all the values of B in A, searching row by row and after I’d like to delete the correspondent column associated to this particular value. I’ve a problem using bsxfun o cellfun and find function with a matrix and a cell array. I‘ve tried to convert the cell array into a matrix but I don’t have more the exact correspondence.

For example:
A =

```
 1     5    10    23
 2     4     2    18
 3     3     5    14
 1     9    10     4
```

B =

```
 1 
 2     4
 3     3    14
 1
```

To obtain:

C =

```
 10
 2
 5
 10
```

Thanks in advance,
L.

Comment: In the second row, `2` appears twice. How do we know which column to delete?

Comment: Its not clearly written, but I think he first wants to search for columns containing [1 2 3 1]', then for columns containing [4 3]' and finally for columns containing 14. From the writing I would guess he only wants to delete 1 column each time (but maybe all of them). --- I suppose the hardest part of this question is finding which column to delete. Here you can find some ways to locate a vector in a matrix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831011/general-method-to-find-submatrix-in-matlab-matrix

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin but it says "row by row" in the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how:

```
C = cellfun(@(x, y){sparse(1,find(ismember(x,y),numel(y)),true,1,size(A,2))}, ...
      mat2cell(A, ones(size(A, 1), 1), size(A, 2)), B(:));
C = A(:, all(~vertcat(C{:})));
```

The `cellfun` is fed with two cell arrays: the first one contains the rows of `A` and second one is `B`. The anonymous function is the tricky part; it operates on a pair of two corresponding rows as follows:

1. It employs `ismember` to check which columns in `A` contain any of the elements in `B`.
2. It uses `find` to pick only the first `N` ones, with respect to the number of elements in the `B`.
3. It uses `sparse` as a fancy way of zeroing out the rest of the elements.

For your example it would look like this:

```
A = [1 5 10 23; 2 4 2 18; 3 3 5 14; 1 9 10 4];         
B = {1; [2 4]; [3 3 14]; 1};

C = cellfun(@(x, y){sparse(1,find(ismember(x,y),numel(y)),true,1,size(A,2))}, ...
    mat2cell(A, ones(size(A, 1), 1), size(A, 2)), B(:));
```

which yields:

```
C =
    {
        [1   0   0   0]
        [1   1   0   0]
        [1   1   0   1]
        [1   0   0   0]
    }
```

After that, it's a simple matter of logical indexing to pick the resulting columns:

```
C = A(:, all(~vertcat(C{:})));
```

which in this case should be:

```
C =  
   10
    2
    5
   10
```