# Sort and keep index of a n-dimension array -- MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, indexing, n-dimensional

I have a 12-D array and am using each dimension as an index value in an optimization problem.

```
A(:,:,i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6,i7,i8,i9,i10)
```

each index value `i` is a value from 1 to 5.

I want to sort `A` from greatest to least and keep track of the indices so I know which indices correspond to to what value of `A`.

So my ideal output would be a 2 column cell/array with one column being the value and the other other column being the index values.

For a simple 3D example: say I have a 3D array:  `A(:,:,i1)`.

Where:

```
A(:,:,1) =  2 
A(:,:,2) =  6 
A(:,:,3) =  13 
A(:,:,4) =  11 
A(:,:,5) =  5
```

I would like my output to be:

```
13   3
11   4
6    2
5    5
2    1
```

EDIT:

assume I have 1x1x3x3 sized input such that

A(1,1,1,1) = 3

A(1,1,2,1) = 1

A(1,1,3,1) = 23

A(1,1,1,2) = 12

A(1,1,2,2) = 9

A(1,1,3,2) = 8

A(1,1,1,3) = 33

A(1,1,2,3) = 14

A(1,1,3,3) = 6

the expected output would be:

33  [1,1,1,3]

23  [1,1,3,1]

14  [1,1,2,3]

12  [1,1,1,2]

9  [1,1,2,2]

8  [1,1,3,2]

6 [1,1,3,3]

3  [1,1,1,1]

1  [1,1,2,1]

Comment: So what would be the size of that output  2 column array? That is how many rows would it have?

Comment: it would be prod(size(A)) which is 9765625

Comment: Can you take a small 3D array instead of 12-D array as an example and show us the expected output?

Comment: I edited the comment to give an example

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but not that simplified. Could you assume `2 x 2 x 2` sized input? Or do you mean you would always have `1 x 1 x M x ..` as input?

Comment: @OliverOliver By the way, in my solution, I give you something like `[1st dim, 2nd dim, ..., 12th dim]`. If you want indices, then don't use `ind2sub`

Comment: @Divakar I always have a 1 x 1 x i1 x i2 x i3 x ...

Comment: Alright, so could you assume `1 x 1 x 5 x 2` sized input and tell us the expected output?

Comment: @Parag S. Chandakkar What should I use instead?

Comment: @Divakar I edited the question to include that

Comment: @OliverOliver see my edit and read the comment carefully. I would have loved to give you a better solution, but running out of time.

Comment: @Parag S. Chandakkar thanks for your help Divakar's solution worked out for me

Comment: Consider accepting the solution that has best met the needs of the question, by clicking on the hollow checkmark at the top-left side of the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a generic code for any multi-dimensional input array -

```
%// Sort A and get the indices
[sorted_vals,sorted_idx] = sort(A(:),'descend'); 

%// Set storage for indices as a cell array and then store sorted indices into it
c = cell([1 numel(size(A))]); 
[c{:}] = ind2sub(size(A),sorted_idx);

%// Convert c to the requested format and concatenate with cell arary version of 
%// sorted values for the desired output
out = [num2cell(sorted_vals) mat2cell([c{:}],ones(1,numel(A)),numel(size(A)))];
```

The generic code owes its gratitude to [this fine solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8918571/3293881).

Comment: well that's the same problem for me. Is there any way we can make this code work for variable dimensionality? Since you also have to specify `[p1,...,p12]`

Comment: @Divakar Thanks so much this works perfectly!! Now I just to to figure out a way to visualize/display this data.

Comment: @OliverOliver isn't the cell used to display your data, for example, in my answer, the cell `yourCell`?

Comment: @Parag S. Chandakkar Yes, it is. I was was just thinking out loud. My next step is to display this output in a plot or something to make it super easy to visualize.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Check out the edits on how to make it generic.

Comment: @OliverOliver So that `out` would be used to get your plot I am assuming?

Comment: @OliverOliver Also, check out the edits, as the code is now less "stretchy", compact and generic! Let us know how it goes with you?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want:

```
b=A(:);
[sorted_b,ind]=sort(b,'descend');
[dim1,dim2,dim3,dim4]=ind2sub(size(A),ind);

%arranging in the form you want
yourCell=cell(size(b,1),2);
yourCell(:,1)=mat2cell(sorted_b,ones(size(b,1),1),1);

%arranging indices -> maybe vectorized way is there for putting values in "yourCell"
for i=1:size(b,1)
    yourCell{i,2}=[dim1(i) dim2(i) dim3(i) dim4(i)];
end
```

For the array `A`, given by you, my output looks like:

```
33  [1,1,1,3]
23  [1,1,3,1]
14  [1,1,2,3]
12  [1,1,1,2]
9   [1,1,2,2]
8   [1,1,3,2]
6   [1,1,3,3]
3   [1,1,1,1]
1   [1,1,2,1]
```

which matches with your output.

Comment: Something does't work when trying to extract the indices back out. I i get this for [3,3,12,2420] for the indices output when trying a 11-D array

Comment: tell exact size of your matrix, as in `m x n x p x...`

Comment: [1   x  1   x  4  x  4  x   4  x   4   x  4  x   4  x   4 x    4 x    4]

Comment: Now I understand, well my code works, but it requires that you specify as many no. of variables as your matrix dimensionality i.e. if your matrix is 4-D. Then you should change `[row,col,layer]=ind2sub(size(a),ind);` to `[dim1,dim2,dim3,dim4]=ind2sub(size(a),ind);` and change `yourCell{i,2}=[row(i) col(i) layer(i)];` to `yourCell{i,2}=[dim1(i) dim2(i) dim3(i) dim4(i)];`. So my code will not work, if you enter variable dimensionality arrays i.e. 12-D, 11-D etc. See the modified code. It works for a 4-D array and it will work for an 11-D array if you write `[dim1,dim2,...,dim11]` as I suggested.

Comment: +1 for you too already and you can use the generic-part if you need to. It's not really an essential part of my code.

Comment: ya I know... our solutions are very similar, I just didn't have time to make it generic, nice job. @OliverOliver Please consider accepting the appropriate solution.

Comment: Comeon I skipped loops! :)

Comment: ya, I didn't pay attention in optimizing that... I even wrote it in solution that "maybe vectorized way is there for putting values in "yourCell""